# css swap images on hover not working properly - hover image displayed behind main image

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have a very simple bit of code that should effectively swap out images on hover. The main img is grey, and the `:hover` img is green. I can see that the green `:hover` img appears on hover, but it's behind the main grey one. How can I make this work so that the grey is not visible on `:hover`?

html

```
<div id="header">
    <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
</div>
```

css

```
#header {
    height: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 960px;
}

#header .logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 185px;
}

#header .logo:hover {
    background: url('img/logo_hover.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified CSS:

```
#header {
    height: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 960px;
}

#header .logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 185px;
    height: 40px; /*added*/
}

#header .logo:hover {
    background: url('img/logo_hover.png') no-repeat;
}

/*added*/
#header .logo img {
    display: block;
}

#header .logo:hover img {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because the classes are messed up.. here is an example of a button that has nothing in text but the source is set up from css // it also gives the hover effect from css:

```
.SubmitClass
{
    background-image: url('../Images/Submit.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.SubmitClass:hover
{
    background-image: url('../Images/SubmitHover.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by the 'classes are messed up'?

Answer (score 0):

You see one image behind the other because you are setting a background image for an image in content.  For an image to be swapped out through hovering over it, you should either set BOTH images in CSS or both in content (and handle the swapping using JavaScript/JQuery).

```
<div id="header">
<a class="logo" href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
</div>
```

In the above html you set an image as content.

You probably can't/don't want to output CSS dynamically using PHP so its more likely you should output both images and toggle their visibility

```
<div id="header">
<a class="logo" href="#"><img class="defaultImage" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
<img class="hoverImg" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/logoHover.png" alt="logo" /></a>
</div>
```

and toggle the images with the following JQuery

```
$(document).on({
   mouseenter: function() {
       $('.hoverImage').show();
       $('.defaultImage').hide();
   },
   mouseleave: function() {
       $('.hoverImage').hide();
       $('.defaultImage').show();
   } 
}, 'a.logo');
```

Alternatively, specify both background images using CSS as per Nathans answer.